# Renaming a newly generated pdf file from a cell in existing sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Renaming a newly generated pdf file from a cell in existing sheet for example, if I edit my sheet for a quotation for a client, i need a script that when it generates its pdf(i got a script which does automatically) it may take new file name as per a cell value like david quote.pdf

Comment: share your script

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130025/how-to-get-and-use-a-value-of-a-cell-in-the-pdf-file-name-exporting-using-that-s)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const value = sheet.getRange(...).getValue();
  const fileName = value + '.pdf';
  const blob = file.getBlob().setName(fileName);
  folder.createFile(blob);
```

Reference:

[setName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setnamename)